# Linux - get shared memory values from Perl script

Tags: perl, shared-memory

I'm trying to get shared memory information from a linux box. I'm looking for shmmax, shmmni, shmall, msgmax, msgmni, semmsl, semmns etc. How to get all those values from a Perl script. any help is appreciated?

Comment: I don't see anything relevant on CPAN.  `IPC::Shareable` doesn't provide access to these settings.  Perhaps @poige's answer is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

Would `sysctl -a|fgrep shm` or `ipcs -l` satisfy your knowledge appetite as starting points?

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Tie::Sysctl`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aSysctl), you could probably (*I didn't test it*) use something along

```
use Tie::Sysctl;

tie %t, 'Tie::Sysctl';
print "shmmax: ".$t{kernel}{shmmax};
```

etc, mildly sugaring plain `/proc/sys` reads.